# No transition or animation when exiting(smoothstate.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using smoothstate.js for page transitions and I'm having problems trying to make the animation exit whenever I click on link going to another page. I have no problems when the page loads since the animations starts properly. When only exiting the page will exit normally without any transition or animation. Here is the code that I have been working on

Index.html

```
<div class="container_12 ">
    <header class="grid_12 scene_element scene_element--fadein">
        <nav class="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

About.html

```
<div class="container_12 ">
    <header class="grid_12 scene_element scene_element--fadein">
        <nav class="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>

<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12 main-page scene_element scene_element--fadeinup">
       Main Page
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scene_element {
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;

    animation-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.scene_element--fadein {
    -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.scene_element--fadeinup{
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

.scene_element--fadeinright{
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    animation-name:fadeInRight;
}


.m-scence.is-exiting .scene_element {
     animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
'use strict';
var $body    = $('html, body'),
    content  = $('#main').smoothState({
        prefetch: true,
        pageCacheSize: 20,
        onStart: {
            duration: 200,
            render: function (url, $container) {
                content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');
                $body.animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                });
            }
        },

        onProgress : {
            duration: 0, // Duration of the animations, if any.
            render: function (url, $container) {
            $('container').addClass('hide')
            }
        },

        onEnd: {
            duration: 0,
            render: function (url, $container, $content) {
                $body.css('cursor', 'auto');
                $body.find('a').css('cursor', 'auto');
                $container.html($content);
                content.toggleAnimationClass('hide');
            }

        }


    }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS animation duration is 1s and the animation duration declared in Js is 0.2s

Here is the **CSS**

```
.scene_element {
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
```

Here is the **Javascript**

```
onStart: {
        duration: 200,
        render: function (url, $container) {
```